# Accessing Kindle Paperwhite With Shattered Screen

Tags: kindle-paperwhite, download

I brought a Kindle last autumn. So far I have only loaded a few books onto it. However my partner has shattered the screen. Is there any way I can pull the books off - two are particularly important - so that I can put them on another device. The price I have been quoted suggests buying another eReader is more sensible.

Comment: If you bought these books from Amazon, they are accessible to you from whichever device you use; i.e. you can download Kindle for PC and download them from there. I don't own a Kindle, so this is just speculation: if you have sideloaded them, you can connect it to your PC with an USB cable and retrieve them, it should be seen as a removable drive (like an USB pendrive); my Kobo works like that, you can give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just connect it to PC and move files from `document` folder as backup. Later you can restore them to new device. Anyways you books bought from amazon will be available on cloud

Comment: Have backed up. A local phone/tablet repairer is having a look at the Kindle on a no fix  - no fee basis