# Is there any way to setup a Kindle with a broken screen?

Tags: download, 4th-generation-kindle

My old Kindle 4 has a totally broken and unresponsive screen for past two years. I can see about 50% of what is actually displayed, the remaining part is completely scrambled.

About 1,5 year ago I started using it as a backup pendrive. It was working like a charm. But, unintentionally, I left it not updated for that whole period of time, i.e. it was last time updated in April 2021.

When I now (December 2022) powered it up, it turned out that it is not accessible like a regular USB drive (like it was 1,5 year ago). That is, it appears in Windows 11 for a 1-2 seconds and then disappears (and thus I cannot [access the `document`](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/a/7313/16860) or any other folder)<sup>1</sup>.

Kindle screen then go on and asks me for providing Wi-Fi network credentials (which were provided previously). This step is impassable / impossible due to fact that most of the on-screen elements needed for configuring wireless network access is behind the shattered part.

Is there anything else I can do around this issue?

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Please, note that I am talking about accessing (and using) my old Kindle as a external USB drive, i.e. for storing my own, personal files. There is no way to retrieve (or update) these backups from any other source than my computer, because there were hand-crafted by me and are not accessible neither [in Amazon](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/7044/accessing-kindle-paperwhite-with-shattered-screen#comment4392_7044) nor in any other source.</sub>